# Trying to generate a secret (fake) bank number for a Discord bot using secrets module, but number will regenerate

Tags: python, botframework, discord.py, bots

Okay, so I have multiple questions.
I'm designing a Discord Bot with my friend for fun that is a lottery-like bot. If you get matching numbers, you win money. Here is the basic code:

```
import discord, os, secrets, string, random
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = os.getenv("TOKEN")
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="jack ")

ltrs = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
bnknm = ''.join(secrets.choice(ltrs) for l in range(10))

accounts = {}

Jackpot = 10000
Jack = 3333

@bot.command(name="cAccount", help="This command creates an account for you.")
async def accountCreation(ctx):
  await ctx.send(f"Alright, {ctx.author.display_name}, an account has been successfully created for you. To retrieve your bank number, type the command 'jack dBank#'.")
  bnknm = ''.join(secrets.choice(ltrs) for l in range(10))
  accounts.update({ctx.author.display_name: bnknm})
  print(accounts)


@bot.command(name="dBank#", help="Sends you your bank account for use in Jackpot games.")
async def bankDM(ctx):
    if ctx.author.display_name in accounts:
        bankNumEmbed = discord.Embed(
        title="Your Bank Number",
        description=
        "The following message will provide you with your bank number, used for transactions and other money stuff.",
        color=0x00ff99)
        bankNumEmbed.add_field(
        name="Following should be kept secret...",
        value=
        f"{ctx.author.display_name}, this is your bank number. Do not share this with anyone else, as it can cause other users to illegally enter your account. **{bnknm}**"
        )
        bankNumEmbed.set_author(name=ctx.author.display_name,
        url="https://google.com",
        icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        bankNumEmbed = await ctx.author.send(embed=bankNumEmbed)

    else:
      await ctx.send("Hey! You have to create an account first. Use the command 'cAccount' to make one.")


@bot.command(name="Jackpot", help="This command lets you collect monney")
async def lottery(ctx):
    lot1 = random.randrange(10)
    lot2 = random.randrange(10)
    lot3 = random.randrange(10)
    lotteryEmbed = discord.Embed(title="Jackpot", description="Time to (maybe) make some big bucks!", color=0xfcd602)
    lotteryEmbed.add_field(name="Get the numbers out", value=f"{lot1}, {lot2}, and {lot3}")
    await ctx.send(embed=lotteryEmbed)
    if lot1 == lot2 == lot3:
      await ctx.send("Hip Hip Horray you got $10,000. To collect your money, type the command 'jack cMoney'.")
    if lot1 == lot2 != lot3:
      await ctx.send("That sad, but good. You get $3.333. To collect your money, type the command 'jack cMoney'")
    if lot1 != lot2 == lot3:
      await ctx.send("That sad, but good. You get $3.333. To collect your money, type the command 'jack cMoney'")
    if lot1 != lot2 != lot3:
      await ctx.send("Oof that sucks. You get nothing.")

@bot.command(name='cMoney', help="This command collects your collection of money for you.")
async def DM(ctx):
  if ctx.author.display_name in accounts:
    await ctx.send(
  "Please type your bank account, to collect your money.")

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

I am trying to design this bot so that it generates a random but secure 'bank number' (which isn't an actual bank number) for users. I store their bank numbers in a dictionary that can be referenced. However, my issue is that the bot regenerates the bank number every time you call it. I don't want it to do that; rather, keep the same bank number.

I tried using a for loop in this context:

```
for value in accounts:
     if **this user's original number is not the same number**:
          bnknm = **the same number**
```

However, I wasn't sure how to execute this. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I figured out that the issue didn't even exist at all! The bank number was actually the same no matter how many times you messaged the bot. I think the issue was that at the beginning of my code, I had an extra definition of my `bnknm` variable, which may have fed incorrect data into the program.